# D3 line chart component not being updated inside useEffect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization, linechart

I'm receiving data for my line chart from API. Every time data updated it doesn't re-draw with a smooth transition but instead it draws new lines on the top of the existing chart. It looks messy. I don't have lifecycles as I'm sing `useEffect`. Is it something to do with `line().remove().merge()`? What am I doing wrong?

[CodeSandbbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-carson-ge5r0?file=/src/LineChart.js)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3
      .select(svgRef.current)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -130 + ")");
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime();
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear();
    const xAxisDateFormat = d3.timeFormat("%b");
    
    // line generator
    const line = d3
      .line()
      .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(1))
      .x((d) => xScale(new Date(d.date)))
      .y((d) => yScale(d.value));

    // draw line chart
    const lines = svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
    lines
      .selectAll(".line-group")
      .data(lineChartData.values)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "line-group")
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colorScale(d.lineColor))
      .attr("d", (d) => line(d.dataset));
  }, [lineChartData]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just clear your svg content before adding new elements.

Instead of:

```
const svg = d3
      .select(svgRef.current)
      .append("g")
```

do:

```
 const svgEl = d3.select(svgRef.current);

 svgEl.selectAll('*').remove();

 const svg = svgEl
      .append('g')
```

Comment: It's a possibility, indeed, but it causes unnecessary insertions/deletions in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

`exit()` is missing in your code:

```js
const lines = svg.append("g")
  .classed("lines", true);
const groups = lines
  .selectAll(".line-group")
  .data(lineChartData.values);

const newGroups = groups.enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed("line-group", true);

newGroups.append("path")
  .classed("line", true)
  .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colorScale(d.lineColor))
  .attr("d", (d) => line(d.dataset));

const oldGroups = groups.exit();
oldGroups.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! I can't see where newGroups being used in your example?

Comment: My purpose was to emphasise that `enter()` returns new items (`newGroups` ) while `exit()`  returns old items (`oldGroups`) you need to delete. Also, it's important to separate the code used to create `<g>` elements from the code that appends `<path>` elements under them (to avoid confusion)... This is a common problem I see in a lot of D3 examples.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on this. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: There is an error in my answer: should be `newGroups.append("path")` instead of `groups.append("path")` (I've fixed it in the answer). Does it help?

Comment: This is what I initially thought as newGroups never actually been used, however it still draws on top of existing chart so I have to go with the solution provided by @edgarkiljak.